# Should I buy the to be released MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro

I know there's another event incoming from Apple and as usual releasing upgraded products like MacBook, AirPods, Mac, iPad, etc..

But what caught my attention is the MacBook Pro, I'm planning to buy the specs below.

```
MacBook Pro 16"
32 GB memory
1 TB SSD
```

I can't decide because Apple is releasing really fast, next year I'm pretty sure there's another MacBook Pro incoming, and I'm afraid it would be really good with new look, etc... because it's a new year (2023) there's a new thing that they will add.

Comment: If you're always chasing the latest thing, there will always be something better around the corner, and you'll never be happy. It's unlikely that you need the extra 20% performance that the M2 Pro is likely to bring; unless you work in very particular industries.

Comment: @benwiggy you're right I see it myself I feel like I'm always chasing the better. I work in web development industry.

Comment: If you work in a consumer-oriented workspace, you should always be testing on something at least 5 years old - what the *average* consumer is likely to be using -  no matter what you create on. Especially since the great transition from cheap desktops to cheap laptops, which took the average speed of the consumer computer back at least five years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mac Buyer's Guide

MacRumour's [Mac Buyer's Guide](https://buyersguide.macrumors.com/#mac) is useful for judging the time until next likely update.

No-one here, or at MacRumour's link above, can provide an authoritative answer about what to buy or when. Only Apple know their release schedule and that is a commercial secret.